# If Child Category checkbox Selected Then Parent checkbox Should be selected Automatically

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have nested Loop For Parent And Child Category,
Now I want If My Child Is selected Then All Parent Of that Child Category Should Be Selected Automatically.
In My code Only One Parent is checked , So how can i do it.
And also If i Uncheck Child Then, Parent Should Be uncheck Automatically
So is that possible.
Thanks in advance.
Here Is My code,

```html
<label>Product Category:</label>
<div class="wk_field wk_category">
<div class="wk_for_validation">
<div id="wk_category_label">CATEGORIES</div>
<div class="wk_cat_container" style="margin-left:0px;">
<span class="wk_minus"> </span>
<span class="wk_foldersign"></span>
<span class="wk_elements wk_cat_name">Gold</span>
<input class="wk_elements" type="checkbox" value="3" name="category[]" id="3">
</div>
<div class="wk_removable wk_cat_container" style="margin-left: 20px;">
<span class="wk_no"></span>
<span class="wk_foldersign"></span>
<span class="wk_elements wk_cat_name">Earrings</span>
<input class="wk_elements" type="checkbox" value="27" name="category[]" onclick="checkParent('3', this)">
</div>
<div class="wk_removable wk_cat_container" style="margin-left: 20px;">
<span class="wk_minusend"></span>
<span class="wk_foldersign"></span>
<span class="wk_elements wk_cat_name">Rings</span>
<input class="wk_elements" type="checkbox" value="26" name="category[]" onclick="checkParent('3', this)" id="26">
</div>
<div class="wk_removable wk_cat_container" style="margin-left: 40px;" >
<span class="wk_no"></span>
<span class="wk_foldersign"></span>
<span class="wk_elements wk_cat_name">Ladies</span>
<input class="wk_elements" type="checkbox" value="37" name="category[]" onclick="checkParent('26', this)">
</div>
<div class="wk_removable wk_cat_container" style="margin-left: 40px;">
<span class="wk_no"></span>
<span class="wk_foldersign"></span>
<span class="wk_elements wk_cat_name">Gents</span>
<input class="wk_elements" type="checkbox" value="36" name="category[]" onclick="checkParent('26', this)">
</div>
<div class="wk_removable wk_cat_container" style="margin-left: 20px;">
<span class="wk_no"></span>
<span class="wk_foldersign"></span>
<span class="wk_elements wk_cat_name">Bangles</span>
<input class="wk_elements" type="checkbox" value="25" name="category[]" onclick="checkParent('3', this)">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkParent(id, ele) {
  var parent = document.getElementById(id);
  if (ele.checked === true) parent.checked = true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I got it right when a child is checked you wanted its parent to be checked, and its parent's parent, and so on till root.
If so, check [*this fiddle I created*](https://jsfiddle.net/L5nknhz6/).

I removed inline event handlers (onclick), associated a `data-parent` attribute to each child, and used the attribute to go up the tree in the following reviewed `checkParent` function:

```
function checkParent(ele) {
  var idparent = ele.getAttribute('data-parent');
  if(idparent){
    var parent = document.getElementById(idparent);
    if (ele.checked === true) parent.checked = true;
    checkParent(parent);
  }
}
```

Also, I didn't understand how exactly you wanted child uncheck event to work, you can try and play with jsfiddle to get that, or point it out more clearly to have further help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Its work for all parent.But if you help me out iF i uncheck the chekbox of child  then parent also should be uncheked.

Comment: @AditiPatel Check this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2g7hf2h/). I just updated checkParent. Watch out if you uncheck a child it unchecks all related parents till root.. even if other children are still checked.

Comment: It should be... if there are another child checked, related parent still checked too, but if parent unchecked, all of its child unchecked too